# How to setup log4j2 asyncQueueFullPolicy

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I am using log4j-core-2.5 for my logging and I would like to Discard items when the logging queue is full. I have determined that this could be applied by using the log4j2.asyncQueueFullPolicy configuration property in log4j.

Could somone please help me with how to apply this configuration in my application.

I am using a file configuration like so...

```
Configurator.initialize("", "log4j-node.xml");
```

My config file looks somthing like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{dd-MMM HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger{1}.%t %-5level] %msg%n"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="DefaultFile" fileName="../logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="../logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log" bufferedIO="true" bufferedSize="32000" immediateFlush="false">
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            ...

        </RollingFile>

        <Async name="AsyncFile">
            <AppenderRef ref="DefaultFile"/>
            <LinkedTransferQueue/>
        </Async>

        <Async name="AsyncConsole">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <LinkedTransferQueue/>
        </Async>

    </Appenders>

    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncConsole"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncFile"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="error" />
        <!-- Log all JDBC parameters -->
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="error" />
        <!-- Log all SQL DDL statements as they are executed -->
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl" level="error" />
        <!-- Log the state of all entities (max 20 entities) associated with the session at flush time -->
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.pretty" level="error" />
        <!-- Log all second-level cache activity -->
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.cache" level="error" />
        <!-- Log transaction related activity -->
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.transaction" level="error" />
        <!-- Log all JDBC resource acquisition -->
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.jdbc" level="error" />
        <!-- Log HQL and SQL ASTs during query parsing -->
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST" level="error" />
        <!-- Log all JAAS authorization requests -->
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.secure" level="error" />
        <!-- Log everything (a lot of information, but very useful for troubleshooting) -->
        <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="error" />

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

First, please upgrade to Log4j 2.10, which fixed [an important issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2031) in this area where log events no longer appear out of order in the log file when the queue is full.

You can configure Log4j2's behaviour via system property `log4j2.AsyncQueueFullPolicy`. See [AsyncQueueFullPolicy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/AsyncQueueFullPolicy.html) and [AsyncQueueFullPolicyFactory](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/AsyncQueueFullPolicyFactory.html). The "Discard" policy with some log level may be of interest.

> Property `log4j2.AsyncQueueFullPolicy` controls the routing
>   behaviour. If this property is not specified or has value `"Default"`,
>   this factory creates `DefaultAsyncQueueFullPolicy` objects.
>
> If this property has value `"Discard"`, this factory creates
>   `DiscardingAsyncQueueFullPolicy` objects. By default, this router
>   discards events of level INFO, DEBUG and TRACE if the queue is full.
>   This can be adjusted with property `log4j2.DiscardThreshold` (name of
>   the level at which to start discarding).